# Multiply newly entered row with another column value and find Total Sum in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, multiplication

I have 4 tables here, I need to multiply newly entered row value in a table with another row and find the total sum using `CustomerId`:

**CustomerTable**:

```
CustomerId Name   EmailId
-------------------------
1          Paul   r@r.com
2          John   J@j.com
```

**LoyaltyPointTable**:

```
LoyaltyPointsId LoyaltyType     Points
---------------------------------------
1               Registration       10
2               Loginstatus         1
3               Downloading        10
4               Redemming           1
5               Sharing            20
6               Refer              10
```

**LoyaltyDetailsTable**:

```
 LoyaltyDetailsId LoyaltyPointsId CustomerId Dates
 -------------------------------------------------
  1                    1            1       2015-01-22 
  2                    2            1       2015-01-22 
  3                    3            2       2015-01-22
  4                    3            1       2015-01-22 
  5                    4            1       2015-01-22
  6                    4            1       2015-01-24 
  7                    5            1       2015-01-24
```

This query works fine for the total sum for each `LoyaltyType`

```
SELECT   
   LoayaltyPointsTable.LoyaltyType,
   COUNT(CustomerTable.CustomerId) AS UserActions,
   SUM(LoayaltyPointsTable.Points) AS TotalPoints 
FROM 
   LoayaltyPointsTable 
JOIN 
   LoyaltyDetailsTable ON LoayaltyPointsTable.LoyaltyPointsId = LoyaltyDetailsTable.LoyaltyPointsId
JOIN
   CustomerTable ON CustomerTable.CustomerId = LoyaltyDetailsTable.CustomerId 
WHERE
   CustomerTable.CustomerId = 1
GROUP BY
   LoyaltyDetailsTable.CustomerId ,LoayaltyPointsTable.LoyaltyType
```

below `RedeemPointsTable` is created with relation to row redeeming in  `LoyaltyPointTable`:

**RedeemPointsTable**:

```
 RedeemPointsId CustomerId ShopName BillNo Amount
 ------------------------------------------------
 1                   1      Mall x  4757    100
 3                   1      Mall y  SH43    50
 4                   1      Mall x  7743    10
 6                   1      Mall x  s34a    60
```

What I am expecting is before calculating the total sum, I want column `Amount` sum `(100+50+10+60) * 1` in `Redeeming` in `LoyaltyPointTable` to be added with total points for each `CustomerId`

**Expected output**

```
LoyaltyType UserActions TotalPoints
-------------------------------------
Downloading     1        10
Loginstatus     1         1
Redemming       4   (100+50+10+60)*1(here using Amount in RedeemPointsTable)
Refer           1        10
Registration    1        10
Sharing         1        20
```

User actions count is 4, it is based on the `Amount` he entered in `RedeemPointsTable`

Should I need to make changes in adding a foreign key column in `RedeemPointsTable` or can you point out my mistake?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query which returns desired result:

```
SELECT 
   LoyaltyPointTable.LoyaltyType, 
   CASE 
      WHEN LoyaltyPointTable.LoyaltyPointsId=4 THEN (SELECT COUNT(amount) FROM RedeemPointsTable where CustomerId=1) 
      ELSE COUNT(CustomerTable.CustomerId) 
   END as UserActions, 
   CASE 
      WHEN LoyaltyPointTable.LoyaltyPointsId=4 THEN (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM RedeemPointsTable where CustomerId=1)*Points
      ELSE SUM(LoyaltyPointTable.Points) 
    END as TotalPoints
FROM 
   LoyaltyPointTable 
JOIN 
   LoyaltyDetailsTable ON LoyaltyPointTable.LoyaltyPointsId =     LoyaltyDetailsTable.LoyaltyPointsId
JOIN
   CustomerTable ON CustomerTable.CustomerId = LoyaltyDetailsTable.CustomerId 
WHERE
   CustomerTable.CustomerId = 1
GROUP BY
   LoyaltyDetailsTable.CustomerId ,LoyaltyPointTable.LoyaltyType
```

You can check it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67436/5)

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, i got this error '  Column 'LoayaltyPoints_T.LoyaltyPointsId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. ' , so then i just added LoayaltyPoints_T.LoyaltyPointsId,LoayaltyPoints_T.Points in group by and it works, i have question can the query be optimized or any new column needed for more optimization ?

Comment: hi, can you answers [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392862/sql-total-sum-with-subtraction-if-new-entry-is-made-in-the-table) , i am doing this sql with your previous query.