# Linq Anonymous type members must be declared in Sub Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

i am trying to convert [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67436/9) SQL query to Linq, to return in a View in asp MVC,

**Expected Output in Linq :**

```
TotalPoints Name

  231       John
```

i get this error in second select new sub query:

> Invalid expression term '.'
>
> Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must
>   be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

**Linq query thus far:**

```
public ActionResult UserTotal()
        {
            List<TotalPointsUser> onetotal = from t in (
    (from LoyaltyDetailsTable in dbpoints.LoyaltyDetailsTable
    where
      LoyaltyDetailsTable.CustomerTable.CustomerId == 1
    group new {LoyaltyDetailsTable.CustomerTable, LoyaltyDetailsTable.LoayaltyPointsTable} by new {
      LoyaltyDetailsTable.CustomerTable.Name,
      LoyaltyPointsId = LoyaltyDetailsTable.LoayaltyPointsTable.LoyaltyPointsId,
      Points = LoyaltyDetailsTable.LoayaltyPointsTable.Points,
      CustomerId = LoyaltyDetailsTable.CustomerTable.CustomerId
    } into g
    select new TotalPointsUser{
      CustomerId = 
      g.Key.LoyaltyPointsId == 4 ? 
        (from RedeemPointsTable in dbpoints.RedeemPointsTable
        where
          RedeemPointsTable.CustomerId == 1
        select new {
          RedeemPointsTable.Amount
        }).Count(p => p.Amount != null) : g.Count(p => p.CustomerTable.CustomerId != null),
      Name=g.Key.Name,
      Points = 
      g.Key.LoyaltyPointsId == 4 ? (
        (from RedeemPointsTable in dbpoints.RedeemPointsTable
        where
         RedeemPointsTable.CustomerId == 1
        select new {
         RedeemPointsTable.Amount
        }).Sum(p => p.Amount) * g.Key.Points) : g.Sum(p => p.LoayaltyPointsTable.Points)
    }))
select new {
  CustomerId = t.Sum(p => p.CustomerId),        // here is the error
  Points= t.Sum(p => p.Points),                // and here
  Name = 
    ((from CustomerTable in dbpoints.CustomerTable
    where
      CustomerTable.CustomerId == 1
    select new {
      CustomerTable.Name
    }).First().Name)
}
           .ToList();
            return View(onetotal);
}
```

**Model class:**

```
public class TotalPointsUser
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; }
}
```

i am newbie to linq, may i know what changes has to be made?

Ant help would be great.

Comment: ``Column1 = .Sum(p => p.TotalUserActions)`` is invalid, use its alias

Comment: I don't get what is intended here: `Column1 = .Sum(p => p.TotalUserActions)`  Maybe this is syntax I'm not familiar with?  Of what object is `Sum` a member?  This reminds me of `With` syntax in VB, but have never seen this in C#.

Comment: try like : ``Column1 = g.Sum(p => p.TotalUserActions)``

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad,hi, when i use g, i gee this error: _The name 'g' does not exist in the current context_

Comment: @stom: I can't tell from the code indentation/formatting what the context even is at that point.  Maybe `t` is the object you're looking for?  You're more familiar with the query than anybody else is, what collection are you trying to sum?

Comment: @David, i am trying to sum Points based on conditions , based on each CustomerId, may [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67436/9) SQL query help you understand

Comment: @stom: That SQL code implies that `t` is the object you're looking for, assuming the names are consistent in this code.  Regardless of what you're conceptually trying to do, the compiler is only interested in the structure of how you're accomplishing it.  Somewhere in your code there exists a collection from which you want to draw a sum.  What variable holds that collection?  That's what you need to use there.  `.Sum` by itself is meaningless, the `Sum` method needs to be invoked from a collection of some kind.

Comment: @David, ya i have other collections , [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28187440/multiply-newly-entered-row-with-another-column-value-and-find-total-sum-in-sql), has the table names and are used as my classes , and the same property names used.

Comment: @stom: I think you're missing a fundamental point here.  The class/property names are useful, but they aren't the name of the variable you're looking for.  In C#, when you want to call an instance method on a variable (or reference any member of a variable), you need to start by referencing the variable.  For example, if the variable is called `t` then you would call `t.Sum()`, you can't just call `.Sum()` and expect the compiler to know what you're talking about.  You might try building up from a much smaller query and using more meaningful variable names in order to make sense of this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69951/discussion-between-stom-and-david).

Answer (score 1):

Your query structure is:

```
from t in (
)
select new {
  Column1 = .Sum(p => p.TotalUserActions),        // here is the error
  Column2 = .Sum(p => p.AllTotalPoints),    // and here
}
```

You must use the `t` alias in result, like this:

```
from t in (
)
select new {
  Column1 = t.Sum(p => p.TotalUserActions),
  Column2 = t.Sum(p => p.AllTotalPoints),
}
```

But you must have such fields in your resulting query, which is not true right now.

I think you should write your query in SQL and transmit it to LINQ step by step. Right now it's very confusing and bug producing.

---

**Update**:
You've got the error because of your code doesn't contain such fileds. What should contain fields `TotalUserActions` and `AllTotalPoints`? Try to sum all `Points` fields, but can't say what the `TotalUserActions` is:

```
from t in (
)
select new {
  Column1 = t.Sum(p => p.TotalUserActions),
  Column2 = t.Sum(p => p.Points),
}
```

Comment: ,when i use 't' alias : i get this error:
TotalPointsUser' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and no extension method 'Sum' accepting a first argument of type TotalPointsUser'

Comment: ,i changed the fields for Expected Resulting query  :  'from t in (
)
select new {
  CustomerId = t.Sum(p => p.CustomerId),
  Points = t.Sum(p => p.Points),
}' , but still i get this error: TotalPointsUser' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and no extension method 'Sum' accepting a first argument of type TotalPointsUser' , i am getting separate points but not able to  sum the collections in sub query

Comment: i have removed the TotalUserActions, now i just want the Total so i used, select new {
  
  Points = t.Sum(p => p.Points), but the error is not resolved

Comment: [this](http://pastebin.com/zd2DFwsp), has the working query which shows all points, and [this](http://imgur.com/8PaFzmd) image shows it, i want to sum all the collections –

Comment: i have updated with another Linq query in above comment, which gives collections of points using CustomerId, so i need to Add those points for final Total