# SQL Total Sum with subtraction if new entry is made in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to find TotalPoints Sum with subtraction if new entry is made in the table,

**TotalPoints Query :**

```
SELECT SUM(t.TotalUserActions) as Actions, sum(t.AllTotalPoints) as TotalPoints,
(select Name from CustomerTable where CustomerId=1) as Name from 
(
SELECT CASE 
      WHEN LoayaltyPointsTable.LoyaltyPointsId=4 THEN (SELECT COUNT(amount) 
      FROM RedeemPointsTable where CustomerId=1) 
      ELSE COUNT(CustomerTable.CustomerId) 
      END as TotalUserActions , CustomerTable.Name,
    CASE 
      WHEN LoayaltyPointsTable.LoyaltyPointsId=4 THEN (SELECT SUM(amount) 
      FROM RedeemPointsTable where CustomerId=1)*Points
      ELSE SUM(LoayaltyPointsTable.Points) 
      END as AllTotalPoints 

FROM
     LoayaltyPointsTable
INNER JOIN
     LoyaltyDetailsTable
on LoayaltyPointsTable.LoyaltyPointsId = LoyaltyDetailsTable.LoyaltyPointsId
INNER  JOIN 
     CustomerTable 
on CustomerTable.CustomerId = LoyaltyDetailsTable.CustomerId

where CustomerTable.CustomerID =1
group by CustomerTable.Name,LoayaltyPointsTable.LoyaltyPointsId,
         LoayaltyPointsTable.Points,CustomerTable.CustomerId
) t
```

**Totalpoints Query Output:**

```
Actions  Totalpoints     Name
30       500             John
```

**PriceTable**

```
Priceid Title Discriptions Pricepoints
    1    abc    abc           400
    2    def    def           500
```

**PriceClaimTable**

```
PriceClaimId CustomerId PriceId
1               1         22
2               2         23
```

Using above table , I am trying to subtract TotalPoints – Pricepoints based on the CustomerId and PriceId in PriceClaimTable
And if there is no new entry in PriceClaimTable based on the Customerid, then just Show Totalpoints without subtraction

Thus far I tried to find the price points

```
select PriceTable.PricePoints from PriceTable  

inner join PriceClaimTable 
on PriceTable.PriceId = PriceClaimTable.PriceId

inner join CustomerTable 
on CustomerTable.CustomerId = PriceClaimTable.CustomerId 

where CustomerTable.CustomerId =1

group by PriceTable.PricePoints
```

This gives me output as:

```
PricePoints
400
```

**Expected output:**

```
TotalPoints:
100                         //  (500-400)
```

How can I subtract the results in one Query and find Total Points Sum based on customerid?

**Other Table Structure:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67436/5

Any help would be great.

Comment: Can make both of these queries a CTE and then join the results? You'll need to add those columns to the select clauses that you'll need for the join.

Comment: @JamesZ, can you show an example

Answer (score 1):

Based on the SQL Fiddle, I made a new attempt, which I believe is correct, although it returns 81 and not 100 for John:

```
;  with LP (CustomerId, Name, UserActions, TotalPoints) as (
SELECT
   C.CustomerId,
   C.Name,
   sum(case when P.LoyaltyPointsId = 4 then isnull(R.RedeemCount, 0) else 1 end),
   sum(P.Points * case when P.LoyaltyPointsId = 4 then isnull(R.RedeemAmount,0) else 1 end)
from
   CustomerTable C
   join LoyaltyDetailsTable D on D.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
   join LoyaltyPointTable P on P.LoyaltyPointsId = D.LoyaltyPointsId
   outer apply (
       select sum(Amount) as RedeemAmount, count(Amount) as RedeemCount 
       from RedeemPointsTable R
       where R.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
   ) R
   group by C.CustomerId, C.Name
),

PP (CustomerId, Pricepoints) as (
    select C.CustomerId, sum(P.Pricepoints)
    from PriceTable P
    join PriceClaimTable C on P.PriceClaimId = C.PriceClaimId
    group by C.CustomerId
)

select 
    LP.CustomerId, LP.Name, LP.UserActions, LP.TotalPoints - isnull(PP.Pricepoints, 0) as Points
from
    LP
    left outer join PP on LP.CustomerId = PP.CustomerId 
order by LP.CustomerId
```

Assumption is that the customer is always found from the loyalty tables, but not necessary from redeem or price tables

SQL Fiddle for this version: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5e379/8

Comment: i have updated the post with PriceTable structure and Other Tables in sqlfiddle, have a look, may be that may help you, by that time i will try your query using CTE

Comment: hi thanks for your efforts, i am trying to find using where customer id =1 , check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28187440/multiply-newly-entered-row-with-another-column-value-and-find-total-sum-in-sql?lq=1) for a clear view

Comment: You can of course add there condition that customerId = 1, it will then only return the first of the rows. By the way, is it really intentional that data from RedeemPointsTable is calculated twice, because there's 2 records for that in LoyaltyDetailsTable. Maybe you're missing a date from there?

Comment: hi, as you said check [this](http://pastebin.com/RjqwfRhQ) , i am not able to use Customer id in With, can you just edit those alone

Comment: I tried, but your SQL was way too messy for me to understand or fix, that's why I wrote my own... which I still believe to be correct based on the tables (except RedeemPointsTable, that doesn't make sense...)

Comment: Ok JamesZ, i understand, Let someone else try, thank you thus far.

Comment: I edited http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5e379/26 and now it shows the same 261 points as your query, and it also is able to deduct the price points.